# Low Seg2Cat Ignore pagination

Tags: low-seg2cat

Even if you put 'ignore_pagination' => 'y' 
still does not work on the page with pagination
ee 2.8.1
Seg2Cat 2.8.0

Comment: What isn't working for you? Please add your code, what output you expected, and what output you actually got. An example URI would also help.